# how to describe a twisted curve in a torus

Tags: algebraic-topology

Consider a torus $T$. The first homology group of the torus has two generators, a cycle that goes around the hole and a cycle that goes around the tube, say $a$ and $b$, respectively. Let $C$ be closed path which is obtained as follows: first cut a small arc on $a$ and a small arc on $b$ as well. Then join the endpoints of $a$ with the endpoints of $b$ so that the orientation is considered. The result is a twisted closed path $C$. Can you describe the path $C$ in better mathematical way. I mean in terms of homology or fundamental group ... etc.

Comment: What you did is called *surgery* along $a$ and $b$. The result $C$ is something which is homologous to $[a]+[b]$.To see this you can take $S$ which are spheres around the intersection points (in your case only 1 I assume) and calculate $C=[a]+[b]-[S]=[a]+[b]$ because $[S]$ is the boundary of disks.

Comment: I see, thank you so much.